# Wrapping FlowPanel across FlexTable doesnt work

Tags: gwt, flextable, flowpanel

I am newbee to GWT,
I have separate class which I use for only displaying LIST,when I say list I basically am using FLEXTABLE to show my data...3 FLEXTABLE places side by side.
So, the problem I am facing here is...If I wrap all these FLEXTABLE with FLOWPANEL none of them get displayed on the screen. If I remove those FLOWPANEL wrapping around these FLEXTABLES all of them gets displayed on the screen.

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you are adding to the flowpanel.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet demonstrating panel's initializations ??/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried like this??

```
    FlexTable f1 = new FlexTable();
    f1.setWidget(...     
    f1.setWidget(...

    FlexTable f2 = new FlexTable();
    f2.setWidget(...     
    f2.setWidget(...


    FlowPanel flowpanel= new FlowPanel();
    flowpanel.add(f1);
    flowpanel.add(f2);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(flowpanel);//may be you forgot this line
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put the add(FLOWPANEL);